# Customize key name in json output of drf serializer based on the value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At first sorry for asking question that was asked a multiple of times before ( i'm pretty sure it was ).
Let's say i have this model relationship:

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Balance"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Balances"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u"Currency", null=True, blank=True)
    count = models.FloatField(verbose_name=u"Count", null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, verbose_name='Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Account(Page):
    ...
```

And those serializers

```
class BalanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = accounts.Balance
    fields = ('pk', 'name', 'count')

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    balance_set = BalanceSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
         model = accounts.Account
         fields = (... , balance_set )
```

So accounts serializer returns me json output like that:

```
{
*some account information*
balance_set:
   { 
   pk: 1
   name: foo,
   count: bar
   }, ...
}
```

But i want it to return me balance_set like this:

```
{
    *some account information*
    balance_set:
       { 
       foo: bar,
       balanceName:balanceCount,
       }
    }
```

I've googled and looked up in docs but wasn't able to understand how to do it.

Comment: What is `balanceName:balanceCount` ? can you give an example?

Comment: Those 2 was just example of balance name and balance count, so is there was balance with name: balanceName and count: balanceCount, after serializing account with such balance it would have turned into this property of balance_set. As example let's say i have account with balances {name:"reputation", count:4, account: 1} and {name:"energy", count:120, account:1}, after serializing i will get such json object: {*account properties*, balance_set:{reputation:4, energy:120}}

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your serializer's `to_representation` to do this

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(AccountSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    balance_set = data.get('balance_set')
    for i in balance_set:
         foo = i.get('name')
         bar = i.get('count')
         data['balance_set'][foo] = bar      
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks the for answer. After applying your solution im getting this balance_set: [{name: count}, {name2:count2}], am i doing something wrong or is there way to get such object balance_set: {name: count, name2: count2}  ?

Comment: Do you get name2 and count2 in data? If not, are they a part of instance? You can `print(data)` to check what you're getting. At this point, the `data` acts like a dictionary and you can edit the key value as you want/

Comment: Name2 and count2 is just another balance with name: name2 and count: count2 before serialization.Ikr that i can add key values to datas, but i'm getting array of these datas, can i transform my balance_set from [{name: count}, {name2: count2}] to {name: count, name2: count2}. I know that all names of balances are unique

Comment: Yes you can do it in a for loop. I'll edit my answer for that